# How to export 3D array into a single row in excel using python

Tags: python, excel, csv, 3d

I am attempting to export a large array of 3D points into excel.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d = np.asarray(data)
df = pd.Dataframe(d)
df.to_csv("C:/Users/Fred/Desktop/test.csv")
```

This exports the data into rows as below:

```
3.361490011 -27.39559937 -2.934410095
4.573401244 -26.45699201 -3.845634521
```

.....

Each line representing the x,y,z coordinates. However, for my analysis, I would like that the 2nd row is moved to columns beside the 1st row, and so on, so that all the coordinates for one shape are on the one row of the excel. I tried turning the data into a string but this returned the above too.

The reason is so I can add some population characteristics to the row for each 3d shape. Thanks for any help that anyone can give.

Comment: I haven't in python for a while but just to clarify the question (only if the answer given doesn't work):  you talk about all the points of one shape, does that mean you want each new shape to be on a new line?  if so how is a shape defined in the data?  i.e. how do you tell the program you want a new line? or is it that you dont want any new lines at all?  hopefully this will help, as i say only if the answer from @MosGeo doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `x = df.to_numpy().flatten()` to flatten your data and then save it to csv using `np.savetxt`.